# How to reencode url parameters with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller

I use the following code with my Zend Framework application:

controller:

```
$paramsOtherAction = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$paramsOtherAction['action'] = 'otheraction'
$this->view->paramsOtherAction = $paramsOtherAction;
```

view:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->paramsOtherAction)?>"> Do other action with same params </a>
```

This works fine, except when there are any characters in the parameters that need to be escaped (encoded), like url's. How can I in the best way encode this array of parameters?

*Edit:*

What I am searching actually is the possibility to pass the a parameter to the url function that makes sure that my url-parameters are encoded (why isn't that done standard anyway?).

Comment: Why don't you modify the url method to do the escaping?

Comment: The url helper, is part of the Zend_View. I can of course make a new helper (extending the old one), but this is such a common use case that I would expect that Zend can do this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of escaping the parameters is to use array_map and urlencode:

```
$paramsOtherAction = array_map('urlencode', $paramsOtherAction);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) function:

```
foreach ( $paramsOtherAction as $key => $value )
{
    $paramsOtherAction[$key] = urlencode ( $value );
}
```

Comment: I guess an array_map('urlencode',$array) would even be better... Maybe I add this as an answer myself